# Azure function cannot write file to filesystem

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I am implementing a **TimerTriggered Azure Function** with **NodeJS**, that should create a **CSV file**, temporarily write it on the filesystem and then upload it to an **SFTP** and a **Blob Storage**.

My problem is that when I write it on the filesystem, I get no error, but the file is never written anywhere. I suspect some configuration issue, probably permission related, even though I would expect an error in that case.

For the creation of the CSV file I am using the `csv-writer` dependency:

```
const createCsv = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {    
    let filePath = "test.csv"
    const csv = await createCsv({
        path: filePath,
        header: [
            {id: "Id", title: "Id"},
            {id: "Name", title: "Name"}
        ]
    });
    let csvRows = [
        {Id: "123456"},
        {Name: "Something"}
    ]
    await csv.writeRecords(csvRows);
};
```

`createCsv` method runs without any exception, but when the `csv.writeRecords` runs, it cannot find the file, so it throws the following exception:

> FailureException: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\test.csv'

Can you please help.

Comment: Eventually I managed to write to the filesystem by switching my subscription from free to a paid one. I created a new Linux-based function app deployed again and then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here I was able to write to the `.csv` by giving the full path to the file and by using promise instead of `await`
- Here I am writing a UUID string every second

```
module.exports = async  function (context, myTimer) {
    const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
    const  createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

    const  csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        // Complete Path
        path:'C:\\Users\\Mohit\\BackEndLearning\\AzureTimeTrigger\\TimerTrigger1\\test.csv',
        header:[
            {id:  'lang', title:  'UUID'}
        ]
    });
    const  records = [
        { lang:  uuidv4().toString()}
    ];
    // Use a Promise
    csvWriter.writeRecords(records)
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("..done");
        });
}
```

Console Logs:

[image]

`.csv`  file :
[image]